# JS HTML DOM Events on w3schools

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn javascript on w3schools, and in one of the examples, it has the following code:

```
<html>
<body>

<div onmouseover="mOver(this)" onmouseout="mOut(this)" style="background-    color:#D94A38;width:120px;height:20px;padding:40px;">Mouse Over Me</div>

<script>
function mOver(obj)
{
obj.innerHTML="Thank You"
}

function mOut(obj)
{
obj.innerHTML="Mouse Over Me"
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When you put your mouse over the block, it says Thank You as desired.  However, if I coded this myself, it would annoy me that the Thank You is not centered in the box.  I played around with it, but could not figure out how to center the Thank You in the box when you mouseover.  Is it possible?

Comment: That's really [not a great resource](http://w3fools.com) for learning *anything*.

Comment: Strange question - you've clearly seen it done but asking it is possible... Obviously answer is yes, but "is it possible" in to very useful question for SO.

Comment: Please provide your code, and perhaps a link to where in their tutorial you got this from. We're glad to help you, but we need to no what you've done to help you fix it.

Comment: A suggestion to read [These articles from Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/) if you intend to learn javascript

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS: `text-align:center;`. I would also separate my JavaScript from HTML. Let's call your first page `index.html`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <title>Looks like your first page</title>
    <style type='text/css'>
      @import 'index.css;
    </style>
  </head>
<body class='njs'>
  <div id='whatever'>Mouse Over Me</div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='common.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='index.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now lets make that CSS page `index.css` seperate

```
#whatever{
  height:20px; width:120px; background:#D94A38; text-align:center; padding:40px;
}
```

Now let's make a common JavaScript page for reuse - `common.js`

```
//<![CDATA[
var doc = document, bod = doc.body, IE = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split('MSIE')[1]);
bod.className = 'js';
function gteIE(version, className){
  if(IE >= version){
    bod.className = className;
  }
}
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
//]]>
```

Now, let's make your page specific JavaScript page - `index.js`

```
//<![CDATA[
var yourDiv = E('whatever');
yourDiv.onmouseover = function(){
  this.innerHTML = 'It Worked';
}
yourDiv.onmouseout = function(){
  this.innerHTML = 'Mouse Over Me';
}
//]]>
```

Comment: I tried that!  I think at least.  I typed: function mOver(obj)
{
obj.innerHTML="Thank You".style.text-align:center
}.  It didn't work

Comment: That is not proper CSS or JavaScript. CSS goes into the HTML `<head>` tag. You should use external CSS for caching into the memory.

Comment: you also should use feature detection not browser detection

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery:

http://jsbin.com/ezuXupI/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var TargID = document.getElementById('bar')

       $(".foo").hover(function(){
          TargID.innerHTML="Thank You"
          $("div").css("background-color", "red");  
          $(".foo").css("text-align", "center"); 
       });

      $(".foo").mouseout(function(){
         TargID.innerHTML="Mouse Over Me"
         $("div").css("background-color", "#D94A38");  
         $(".foo").css("text-align", "left"); 

    });
});

<div class="foo" id="bar" style="background- color:#D94A38;width:220px;height:20px;padding:40px;">Mouse Over Me</div>
```